# Computing the integral $\iiint_D\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~\mathrm{d}z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

> Computing the integral
>
> $$\iiint_D\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~\mathrm{d}z$$
>
> where $D$ is the portion of the ball $x^2 +  y^2 + z^2 \leq 16$ that satisfies $z \geq 2$.
>
> (a) Evaluate this integral using cylindrical coordinates.
>
> (b) Evaluate this integral using spherical coordinates.

The solution I found was $\frac{8\pi}{3}$ as answer for both, cylindrical and spherical.
[Cylindrical coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTkiC.png)

$\iiint\limits_D \frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} dV = \int\limits_{0}^{4}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\rho^2 \cos{\phi} \sin{\phi}}{\rho^3} \sin{\phi} d\rho d\phi d\theta = \frac{8\pi}{3}$

[Espherical coordinates][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvUEC.png
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \int_{0}^{4} \frac{\rho \cos\phi \sin\phi}{\rho^3} \rho^2 \sin\phi ,d\rho,d\phi,d\theta &= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \int_{0}^{4} \cos\phi \sin^2\phi ,d\rho,d\phi,d\theta \
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \left[\frac{\rho\cos\phi \sin^2\phi}{-2}\right]0^4 ,d\phi,d\theta \
&= \int{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/3} -8\cos\phi \sin^2\phi ,d\phi,d\theta \
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left[\frac{2\cos^3\phi}{3}\right]0^{\pi/3} ,d\theta \
&= \int{0}^{2\pi} \frac{2}{3} \left(1 - \frac{1}{8}\right) ,d\theta \
&= \frac{8\pi}{3}.
\end{align*}

Then, it also gives  $\frac{8\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. *How* did you get that solution?

Comment: Thanks! I would like to show you but I don't know where to show it. I can't post it here as it is too much text. Thanks for answering once again

Comment: Can you read it better now? I am so worried about this exercise

Comment: You should include your attempt in your question, and not as an answer, if that's what you want help with

Comment: Didn't know how to show my attempt after posting the question so I answered myself, sorry. Well, the main help I need is to know if the exercise is well done

Comment: Then move the information from your answer to your question. You can edit these things. If you do, I'll remove my vote to close it

Comment: Better now? Just want to learn and check my exercise. Thanks for teaching me how to write here correctly. I just have issues to deal with computers

Answer (score 0):

You have computed the integral$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\int_0^4\frac{\rho^2\cos(\varphi)\sin(\varphi)}{\rho^3}\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\varphi\,\mathrm d\theta,$$which is *not* the integral that you should be computing, since it corresponds to the integral of the given function over $D$ *together with* the cone whose vertex is the origin and whose base is the circle at the bottom of $D$. So, you are integrating of a larger region than $D$.

You can compute your integral using cylindrical coordinates:\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_2^4\int_0^{\sqrt{16-z^2}}\frac{z\rho}{(\rho^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\theta&=2\pi\int_2^41-\frac z4\,\mathrm dz\\&=\pi.\end{align}

If you want to, you can use spherical coordinates:\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\int_{2\sec(\varphi)}^4\cos(\varphi)\sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\varphi\,\mathrm d\theta&=2\pi\int_0^{\pi/3}4\cos(\varphi)\sin(\varphi)-2\sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm d\varphi\\&=\pi.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! And how can I make the same result for espherical?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the value of an integral might depend upon that change of variables that we use to compute it?

Comment: No, I mean the process

Comment: There was an error in my answer, and I have corrected in. If you want to use spherical coordinates, you compute$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\int_{2\sec(\varphi)}^4\cos(\varphi)\sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\varphi\,\mathrm d\theta.$$And you will get the same answer as I got above.